# Merge two objects return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have two `Object` and want to merge these two objects. one object create after `click` in *ADD TO CART* section then I store this object to `localstorage`, second object got from `localstorage` now I want to merge these two `object` after click. here is my code:

```js
/***********************************RESTORE CART *********************************************/

var html = '';
var p = 0;
var q = 0;

//var cartS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
// for remove error I managed to set empty object

var cartS = new Object();

$.each(cartS, function(i, v) {
  html += '<div class="cart-item" data-id="' + cartS[i].id + '">' + cartS[i].title + '<span> × ' + cartS[i].quantity + '</span> ' + cartS[i].price + ' $</div>';
  p += Number(cartS[i].price * cartS[i].quantity);
  q += cartS[i].quantity;
});
$('#cart').empty().html(html);
$('#total').empty().html('Total price: ' + p + ' $');
$('#count').empty().html('Total Items: ' + q);

/***********************************ADD TO CART *********************************************/

const cart = {};

$('li').click(function(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  const title = $(this).text();
  const price = e.target.dataset.price;

  var html = '';
  var p = 0;
  var q = 0;

  if (!cart[id]) cart[id] = {
    id,
    title,
    price,
    quantity: 0
  }
  cart[id].quantity++;

  $.each(cart, function(i, v) {
    html += '<div class="cart-item" data-id="' + cart[i].id + '">' + cart[i].title + '<span> × ' + cart[i].quantity + '</span> : ' + cart[i].price + ' $</div>';
    p += Number(cart[i].price * cart[i].quantity);
    q += cart[i].quantity;
  });

  $('#cart').empty().html(html);
  $('#total').empty().html('Total price:' + p + ' $');
  $('#count').empty().html('Total Items: ' + q);

  //localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart)); // store objects in localstorage
});
```

```css
#total {
  color: green;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.cart-item {
  background: #ffe1e1;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-id="1" data-price="50">Product 1</li>
  <li data-id="2" data-price="25">Product 2</li>
  <li data-id="3" data-price="15">Product 3</li>
  <li data-id="4" data-price="50">Product 4</li>
</ul>

<div id="cart"></div>
<br><br>
<a id="total"></a>
<a id="count"></a>
```

What I tried:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(cart,cartS);
```

Also:

```
$.merge( cartS, cart );
```

But it's won't merge.

Note that snippet return an error, because SO not support `localstorage`.

**GOAL:**

I create object after click, and store it on localstorage, then after page reload, I got object from localstorage, now want if user click, merge current object with second one that I got from localstorage. It's similar to shop cart.

Comment: So which one is it? Object `{}` or Array `[]` (*though arrays are also object, let's stick to the common knowledge*)? It would also be good to give sample data of the two ***"Objects"*** and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.assign method to merge two Objects.

```
let newObject = Object.assign(cart, cartS)
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: cart.concat is not a function`

Comment: `cart` is an object not an array, you can use `Array.concat` on it

Comment: @tourtravel, Yeah, I checked that and changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Terry, Actually, OP was trying to merge two arrays. That's why I answered for arrays. I read the code and changed that.

Comment: I don't think so: `var cartS = new Object();` clearly creates a new object. So does `const cart = {};`

Comment: @Terry, The first thing I saw was, what he tried, so I answered for Arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

Both `cartS` and `cart` are objects instead of arrays. Instead of using `$.merge`, which is for arrays only, consider using [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```
$.extend( cartS, cart );
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.merge()` is for merging two *arrays*. `cart` and `cartS` are plain objects, not arrays.

But why do you have two separate objects for cart anyway? You could just directly update the object you have read from the localStorage.